# Accurately timed downloads with Wget

Tags: batch-file, time, windows-xp, wget

I am downloading 1 image that changes each time the site is accessed 4 times. There must be exactly one second between each downloaded image. The image takes a few milliseconds to download however the problem comes that each image will have a different and unpredictable file size and therefore will take a different time to download each time. This is making it very difficult to space these images exactly 1 second apart.

Is it possible to set a specific amount of time that wget has to download a webpage? Or is there any other method using a command line in windows that would be able to achieve this?

Comment: Is the windows command line here DOS?  Or some other shell?

Comment: DOS, its actually running from a .bat file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DOS, I'm playing with `START /B` to background commands and `TIMEOUT /T #` to do what you want.   You could try:

```
START /B wget blah0 & TIMEOUT /T 1 & START /B wget blah1 & TIMEOUT /T 1 & START /B wget blah2 ...
```

... assuming the command line you mention is cmd.exe.  Though this is ugly because each START spawns a new terminal.  But it's already ugly because it's DOS...

Comment: My machine that I am testing this on runs XP so no luck with the timeout command but I achieved something similar with sleep.exe. Unfortunately each downloads are still randomly off by a few milliseconds. I'm not sure if sleep.exe was designed for high accuracy timing or if there's another error. I'll keep trying

Comment: I retagged this question with batchfile and windows-xp tags.  There are some batch wizards on here that would not have seen this when it was tagged command-line.

Comment: Thanks so much - I've actually managed to find another solution to the problem using a different method but I'll mark your reply as the answer as it got close!